# Average DeltaV applied to a comet during outgassing?

Tags: orbit, comets

Comets' orbits often change during perihelion passage due to the outgassing of volatiles. So I am wondering, how much change in velocity is applied each perihelion pass? What does this depend on?

Comment: All comets are different. And each one changes on each orbit, so there is no answer here - it is hugely variable. Your best bet if you want to know historical values is to look them up for each comet where the data has been recorded.

Comment: I think you can adjust the question to ask for specific examples, or for a resource where orbital solutions are used to extract "non-gravitational accelerations". See for example [Did Rosetta improve on models of non-gravitational effects on comet 67P's orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18474/12102)