# Specific impulse of cometary outgassing?

Tags: comets, gas

**Note:** This question is related to [Average DeltaV applied to a comet during outgassing?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/31410)

Rocket engines have a parameter called "specific impulse," which is the measurement (in seconds) of how efficient the propellant consumption is. As comets propel themselves via geysers near perihelion, I am wondering how efficient this process is in terms of specific impulse. Has this been directly measured?

Comment: What do you mean by "how efficient" it is, or by "comets propel themselves"? Neither of these is clear. Comets outgas. It causes velocity changes. But efficiency - how would you define it?

Comment: @RoryAlsop See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse, how much mass is ejected per unit velocity change.

Comment: I don't have any misunderstanding as to what specific impulse is. But what does your question mean? What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Since $v_e = g_0  I_{sp}$ this is equivalent to asking what the *effective velocity* of cometary outgassing is and avoid the confusion with rockets. You could just as for typical or average velocity.

Comment: It's been modeled https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10569-020-09973-5.pdf not sure if it's ever been measured.